# How to gather the result of Web APIs on nodeJS with 'request' and 'async'

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I'm writing a test code which gathers the result from Web APIs on node.js by using 'request.js' and 'async.js'.

Here's my sample code;

```
var request = require('request');
var async = require('async');

var addresses = [
    "Tokyo",
    "Moscow",
    "Bagdhad",
    "Mountain View",
    "New York",
];

function accessUrl( address, callback ) {  
    options ={
        headers: {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'},
        url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + address,
        json: true
    };

    request.get(options, function(err, response, body_json) {
        if( !err && response.statusCode === 200 ){
            return callback(address, body_json);
        }
        else{
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
}

function showContent( address, body_json ) {
    console.log( "%s : %s, %s (C)", address, body_json['weather'][0]['main'],
                 Math.round(body_json['main']['temp']-273.15));
    return [ address, body_json['weather'][0]['main'],
                 Math.round(body_json['main']['temp']-273.15)];
}

var result = [];
async.map( addresses, function( item, callback ) {
    result.push (accessUrl( item, showContent ));
    }, function(err) {
    });

console.log(result);
```

However, the result is;

```
~$ node asyncsample1.js
[ undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined ]
Tokyo : Clear, 23 (C)
Mountain View : Mist, 10 (C)
Bagdhad :  Clear, 10 (C)
New York : Clear, 22 (C)
Moscow : Clouds, 4 (C)
```

console.log() in the callback function showContent() shows the proper result but the gathered results are all 'undefined'.

How can I get the results in var result[]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, let me introduce you to `async`'s `concat` function. Here is your modified program.

```
var request = require('request');
var async = require('async');

var addresses = [
    "Tokyo",
    "Moscow",
    "Bagdhad",
    "Mountain View",
    "New York",
];

function accessUrl( address, callback ) {  
    options ={
        headers: {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'},
        url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + address,
        json: true
    };

    request.get(options, function(err, response, body_json) {
        if( !err && response.statusCode === 200 ){
            return callback(null, [[ address, body_json['weather'][0]['main'],
                 Math.round(body_json['main']['temp']-273.15)]]);
        }
        else{
            return callback(err);
        }
    });
}

async.concat (addresses, accessUrl, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

**Output**

```
[ [ 'Mountain View', 'Haze', 17 ],
  [ 'Bagdhad', 'Clear', 18 ],
  [ 'New York', 'Clear', 26 ],
  [ 'Tokyo', 'Clouds', 22 ],
  [ 'Moscow', 'Clouds', 3 ] ]
```

You don't have to synchronize the results yourself. `concat` does that for you.

If you are interested to know how async's concat works, try this

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You are pushing undefined to results here, because accessUrl is asynchronous. It returns undefined. You don't have any result until the accessUrl callback is executed - but by that point, even though it returns a result, undefined has already been pushed and the result goes nowhere.

```
// wrong
var result = [];
async.map( addresses, function( item, callback ) {
    result.push (accessUrl( item, showContent ));
    }, function(err) {
    });
```

Any logic that depends on the result of an asynchronous function must go in the callback of that function. Also, `async` handles the output array for you, you just pass `(err, result` to the iterator.

```
//corrected
async.map( addresses
, function( item, callback ){
  accessUrl( item, function(address, body_json){
    result = showContent(address, body_json);
    // tell async.map there was no error and this is the mapped result
    callback(null, result); 
  });
}
, function(err, results) {
  console.log(results)
});
```

If I were you I would make a couple tweaks. First off handle the case where there is a request error. Second, I like to use `done` as the name for the callback within async, because I commonly find that I use async inside another asynchronous function, and I usually have an existing variable called `callback` already that is the callback of the parent function. So here is how I would do it:

```
//improved
function iterator(item, done){
  accessUrl( item, function(err, address, body_json){
  // you will have to tweak accessUrl to callback with three parameters instead of two

    if(err){ return done(err) }; 
    // the `return` is necessary, otherwise latter lines will still execute

    result = showContent(address, body_json);

    // tell async.map there was no error and this is the mapped result
    done(null, result); 
  });
};

async.map( addresses
, iterator
, function(err, results) {
  if(err){ console.log(err) };
  console.log(results)'
});
```

An alternative way, where you create a results array and add the results one by one. this is closer to your original idea, but since `async.map` automatically builds the results array, it didn't make sense to use this strategy with async.map.

```
//alternative
function printWeather(callback){
  var results = [];
  async.forEachSeries(addresses
  , function(item, done){
    accessUrl( item, function(err, address, body_json){
      if(err){ return done(err) }; 
      result = showContent(address, body_json);
      results.push(result);
      done(null); 
    });
  }
  , function(err) {
    if(err){ console.log(err) };
    console.log(results);
    //callback(err, results);
  });
};
```

Comment: And let me confirm, does 'result' have to be handled only in async.map 'function(err, results){}'?

Comment: The `async.map` function takes the addresses array and executes the iterator function on each item. Each time the iterator function is called, it calls back `(err, result)` where result is the mapped output of that one address. The completion callback of `async.map` takes `(err, results)` parameters, where results is the mapped outputs, in the same order that the addresses array was.

Comment: see my latest edit for an alternative that manually adds results one by one